# SOCKET auditd hex value meaning

Tags: linux, socket, linux-audit, hex

I have the following log messages from auditd. They appear to log calls to socket.

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(05/11/2023 23:19:52.913:2533) : 
arch=x86_64 syscall=socket success=yes exit=9 
a0=inet a1=SOCK_DGRAM a2=ip a3=0x7f1b009852d0 
items=0 ppid=1484 pid=13953 
auid=gwill uid=gwill gid=gwill euid=gwill suid=gwill fsuid=gwill egid=gwill sgid=gwill fsgid=gwill 
tty=(none) ses=3 comm=pool 
exe=/usr/libexec/gvfsd-smb-browse subj=user_u:user_r:user_t:s0 key=SOCKET
```

What does the hex value `a3=0x7f1b009852d0` mean?